# Handling whitespace in EBNF

Tags: parsing, syntax, ebnf

Let's say I have the following EBNF defined for a simpler two-term adder:

```
<expression>    ::= <number> <plus> <number>
<number>        ::= [0-9]+
<plus>          ::= "+"
```

Shown [here](https://bnfplayground.pauliankline.com/?bnf=%3Cexpression%3E%20%3A%3A%3D%20%3Cnumber%3E%20%3Cplus%3E%20%3Cnumber%3E%0A%3Cnumber%3E%20%20%20%20%3A%3A%3D%20%5B0-9%5D%2B%0A%3Cplus%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%3A%3A%3D%20%22%2B%22&name=Adder).

What would be the proper way to allow any amount of whitespace except a newline/return between the terms? For example to allow:

```
1 + 2
1 <tab> + 2
1           + 2
```

etc.

For example, doing something like the following fails:

```
<whitespace>::= " " | \t
```

Furthermore, it seems (almost) every term would be preceded and followed by an optional space. Something like:

```
<plus>          ::= <whitespace>? "+" <whitespace>?
```

How would that be properly addressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML standard, as an example, uses the following production for [whitespace](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-S):

```
S ::= (#x20 | #x9 | #xD | #xA)+
```

You could omit CR (`#xD`) and LF (`#xA`) if you don't want those.

Regarding your observation that grammars could become overwhelmed by whitespace non-terminals, note that whitespace handling can be done in lexical analysis rather than in parsing.  See [EBNF Grammar for list of words separated by a space](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12712446/290085).